# Mosaic DEM has large pixel when displayed in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, mosaic, pixel

I created a mosaic dataset in ArcMap 10.2 from tiles of ASTER DEM's at 30m resolution. I am attaching the image of what my export looks like. You can see that there are extremely large, alternating pixels. These are apparent upon export to a pdf of tiff and also when you zoom way-in in data view in Arc. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do these appear in the mosaic dataset or the original image when viewed in catalog or ArcMap? It is possibly an artifact of the export/print process. What format/compression are the original images?

Comment: These appear in the original image in Arcmap, so my suspicion is that it is not part of the export process. The original image format is: uncompressed size 296.68 MB, format AMD, cell size 0.00027777778, 0.00027777778, number of bands 1, 16 bit.

Comment: However, that was for the mosaic. The original tiles are: compression LZ77, uncompressed size 24.73 MB, format FGDBR, 16 bit, pyramids level: 5, resampling: Nearest Neighbor

Comment: I also noticed that each tile within the mosaic, when zoomed in, has different-sized pixels of the alternating colors.